# Automatically adjust table's column width

Tags: tables, lyx

I am a beginner in Latex. I use Lyx to create tables and then I export the `pdflatex` script which I can simply paste in Overleaf. I am trying to create a table as follows.

[image]

As you can see the column width for column 4,5 and 8 is unnecessarily wide which takes my table almost to the edge of the page. I used nested table so that the column width decreases, but it seems it does nothing.

Here, is the `pdflatex` exported from Lyx.

```
%% LyX 2.3.6.1 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{array}

\makeatletter

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% LyX specific LaTeX commands.
%% Because html converters don't know tabularnewline
\providecommand{\tabularnewline}{\\}

\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}

\caption{Problem 1: Summary of parameters and relative $L^{2}$ error for different
PINN frameworks\label{tab:Problem-1:-Summary}}

\begin{centering}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline 
 & Layers & Nodes & %
\begin{tabular}{c}
Boundary\tabularnewline
points\tabularnewline
\end{tabular} & %
\begin{tabular}{c}
Collocation\tabularnewline
points\tabularnewline
\end{tabular} & $\alpha$ & Iterations & %
\begin{tabular}{c}
Relative $L^{2}$\tabularnewline
error\tabularnewline
\end{tabular}\tabularnewline
\hline 
Model 1 & 8 & 20 & 612 & 5800 & 1e-3 & 30k & 0.13599\tabularnewline
\hline 
Model 2 & 8 & 20 & 800 & 2500 & 1e-3 & 30k & NA\tabularnewline
\hline 
Model 3 & 6 & 512 & 4000 & 4000 & 1e-3 & 20k & 0.08931\tabularnewline
\hline 
Model 4 & 6 & 512 & 4000 & 4000 & 1e-3 & 10k & 0.10124\tabularnewline
\hline 
Model 5 & 6 & 512 & 4000 & 4000 & 1e-3 & 10k & 0.09557\tabularnewline
\hline 
Model 6 & 6 & 512 & 4000 & 4000 & 1e-3 & 20k & 0.06448\tabularnewline
\hline 
Model 7 & 6 & 512 & 4000 & 4000 & 1e-3 & 20k & 0.06433\tabularnewline
\hline 
Model 8 & 6 & 512 & 4000 & 4000 & 1e-3 & 20k & 0.18741\tabularnewline
\hline 
Model 9 & 6 & 512 & 4000 & 4000 & 2e-5 & 11k & 0.12640\tabularnewline
\hline 
Model 10 & 6 & 512 & 4000 & 4000 & 1e-3 & 20k & 0.17577\tabularnewline
\hline 
Model 11 & 6 & 512 & 4000 & 4000 & 1e-3 & 30k & 0.08229\tabularnewline
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\par\end{centering}
\begin{raggedright}
{*} From Model 3 to Model 11, the boundary points and collocation
points are given for per batch.
\par\end{raggedright}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

I know I can manually set the column width in centimeters or inches. Isn't there an automated way to set the column width? I have multiple tables and I don't want to tinker them manually.

EDIT 1:
Here are the options in Lyx.
[image]

Comment: Just keeping to "pure" LaTeX, you can use the `p` column type instead of `c`, but I've never used LyX so I don't know if you have control over this. A better solution would be to use a package providing that feature, like `tabularray` or the older `tabularx`. Is this possible in LyX?

Comment: I have added the screenshot of table settings in Lyx.

Comment: Does the "horizontal alignment" option at the top offer a "paragraph" type of column? If yes, that's the `p` type I was mentioning and it accepts a specified width.

Comment: I have got `Center`, `Left`, `Right` and `At Decimal separator` in the horizontal alignment.

Comment: Assuming that those are the default LaTeX types (except the last one, which is likely provided by `siunitx`) then you may be out of luck. I'll let people actually familiar with LyX give a proper answer, though. Sorry.

Comment: thanks a lot for the help. I appreciate it.

Comment: You must learn about the packages `tabularx` and `tabulary`. Unfortunately,  LyX only can manage `tabular` and `longtable`,  but you can put both packages in the LaTeX preamble, make a simple tabular  in LyX, copy the corresponding code in the  Code Preview Pane, paste it as  Evil Red Text (Ctrl-L) and change the first line as needed to use type of columns supplied by one or the other packages  (e.g.  `\begin{tabular}{crclrc}`  to `\begin{tabulary}{\linewidth}{crCLRJ}` or `\begin{tabulary}{\linewidth}{crXXXX}`) and obviously,  change also the  end of the environment accordingly.

Comment: I fixed it. Instead of nested table, I used `textwidth` = 12.5% i.e. 100/8 columns and it worked in Overleaf. Should I delete the question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is due to the preamble of the nested tabulars (for the column heads). You can replace each `{c}` with `{@{]c@{}}`, or simpler, use the `makecell` package and its eponymous command. Furthermore, the table is too wide for the default text width, so I suggest loading `geometry`. Also, I loaded  `caption`  to have a more sensible spacing between the caption and the table.

```
        \documentclass[english]{article}
        \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
        \usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
        \usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
        \usepackage{array, caption}
        \usepackage{makecell}
        \makeatletter

        %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% LyX specific LaTeX commands.
        %% Because html converters don't know tabularnewline
        \providecommand{\tabularnewline}{\\}

        \makeatother
        \usepackage{babel}

        \begin{document}

        \begin{table}

        \caption{Problem 1: Summary of parameters and relative $L^{2}$ error for different
        PINN frameworks\label{tab:Problem-1:-Summary}}


        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
        \hline
         & Layers & Nodes & %
        \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
        Boundary\tabularnewline
        points\tabularnewline
        \end{tabular} & %
        \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
        Collocation\tabularnewline
        points\tabularnewline
        \end{tabular} & $\alpha$ & Iterations & %
        \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
        Relative $L^{2}$\tabularnewline
        error\tabularnewline
        \end{tabular}\tabularnewline
        \hline
        Model 1 & 8 & 20 & 612 & 5800 & 1e-3 & 30k & 0.13599\tabularnewline
        \hline
        Model 2 & 8 & 20 & 800 & 2500 & 1e-3 & 30k & NA\tabularnewline
        \hline
        Model 3 & 6 & 512 & 4000 & 4000 & 1e-3 & 20k & 0.08931\tabularnewline
        \hline
        Model 4 & 6 & 512 & 4000 & 4000 & 1e-3 & 10k & 0.10124\tabularnewline
        \hline
        Model 5 & 6 & 512 & 4000 & 4000 & 1e-3 & 10k & 0.09557\tabularnewline
        \hline
        Model 6 & 6 & 512 & 4000 & 4000 & 1e-3 & 20k & 0.06448\tabularnewline
        \hline
        Model 7 & 6 & 512 & 4000 & 4000 & 1e-3 & 20k & 0.06433\tabularnewline
        \hline
        Model 8 & 6 & 512 & 4000 & 4000 & 1e-3 & 20k & 0.18741\tabularnewline
        \hline
        Model 9 & 6 & 512 & 4000 & 4000 & 2e-5 & 11k & 0.12640\tabularnewline
        \hline
        Model 10 & 6 & 512 & 4000 & 4000 & 1e-3 & 20k & 0.17577\tabularnewline
        \hline
        Model 11 & 6 & 512 & 4000 & 4000 & 1e-3 & 30k & 0.08229\tabularnewline
        \hline
        \end{tabular}
        \vskip 3ex
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
        \hline
         & Layers & Nodes & %
        \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
        Boundary\tabularnewline
        points\tabularnewline
        \end{tabular} & %
        \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
        Collocation\tabularnewline
        points\tabularnewline
        \end{tabular} & $\alpha$ & Iterations & %
        \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
        Relative $L^{2}$\tabularnewline
        error\tabularnewline
        \end{tabular}\tabularnewline
        \hline
        Model 1 & 8 & 20 & 612 & 5800 & 1e-3 & 30k & 0.13599\tabularnewline
        \hline
        Model 2 & 8 & 20 & 800 & 2500 & 1e-3 & 30k & NA\tabularnewline
        \hline
        Model 3 & 6 & 512 & 4000 & 4000 & 1e-3 & 20k & 0.08931\tabularnewline
        \hline
        Model 4 & 6 & 512 & 4000 & 4000 & 1e-3 & 10k & 0.10124\tabularnewline
        \hline
        Model 5 & 6 & 512 & 4000 & 4000 & 1e-3 & 10k & 0.09557\tabularnewline
        \hline
        Model 6 & 6 & 512 & 4000 & 4000 & 1e-3 & 20k & 0.06448\tabularnewline
        \hline
        Model 7 & 6 & 512 & 4000 & 4000 & 1e-3 & 20k & 0.06433\tabularnewline
        \hline
        Model 8 & 6 & 512 & 4000 & 4000 & 1e-3 & 20k & 0.18741\tabularnewline
        \hline
        Model 9 & 6 & 512 & 4000 & 4000 & 2e-5 & 11k & 0.12640\tabularnewline
        \hline
        Model 10 & 6 & 512 & 4000 & 4000 & 1e-3 & 20k & 0.17577\tabularnewline
        \hline
        Model 11 & 6 & 512 & 4000 & 4000 & 1e-3 & 30k & 0.08229\tabularnewline
        \hline
        \end{tabular}
        \end{table}

        \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I'm not familiar with `LyX` and conversion to `html`, so I don't know, if proposd solution work well there.  Anyway, use of `tabularx` for table and `siunitx` for present numbers in sixth (`\alpha`) column, code is simple and table looks nice:

[image]

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[skip=0.33\baselineskip]{caption}

\makeatletter
%% LyX specific LaTeX commands.
%% Because html converters don't know tabularnewline
\providecommand{\tabularnewline}{\\}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
\caption{Problem 1: Summary of parameters and relative $L^{2}$ error for different PINN frameworks}
\label{tab:Problem-1:-Summary}

    \centering
    \setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}
    \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|C|C|C|C|C|S[table-format=1e2]|C|C|}
    \hline
    & Layers
        & Nodes
            & Boundary points
                &  Collocation points
                    & {$\alpha$}
                        & Iterations
                            & Relative $L^{2}$ error   \\
    \hline
Model 1 & 8 & 20 & 612 & 5800 & 1e-3 & 30k & 0.13599    \\
    \hline
Model 2 & 8 & 20 & 800 & 2500 & 1e-3 & 30k & NA\tabularnewline
\hline
Model 3 & 6 & 512 & 4000 & 4000 & 1e-3 & 20k & 0.08931\tabularnewline
\hline
Model 4 & 6 & 512 & 4000 & 4000 & 1e-3 & 10k & 0.10124\tabularnewline
\hline
Model 5 & 6 & 512 & 4000 & 4000 & 1e-3 & 10k & 0.09557\tabularnewline
\hline
Model 6 & 6 & 512 & 4000 & 4000 & 1e-3 & 20k & 0.06448\tabularnewline
\hline
Model 7 & 6 & 512 & 4000 & 4000 & 1e-3 & 20k & 0.06433\tabularnewline
\hline
Model 8 & 6 & 512 & 4000 & 4000 & 1e-3 & 20k & 0.18741\tabularnewline
\hline
Model 9 & 6 & 512 & 4000 & 4000 & 2e-5 & 11k & 0.12640\tabularnewline
\hline
Model 10 & 6 & 512 & 4000 & 4000 & 1e-3 & 20k & 0.17577\tabularnewline
\hline
Model 11 & 6 & 512 & 4000 & 4000 & 1e-3 & 30k & 0.08229\tabularnewline
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\begin{raggedright}
{*} From Model 3 to Model 11, the boundary points and collocation
points are given for per batch.
\par\end{raggedright}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```